# React props id binding to onClick in a stateless component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onclick

I have a class based component that is passing props down

```
onClickHandler = () => {doSomething};

return (
   <Container 
    jobs={this.props.jobs}
    clicked={this.onClickHandler}
   />
);
```

...to a stateless component:

```
const Container = props => {

 return (
  <div>
   {props.jobs.map(job => 
     <p onClick={props.clicked} key={job.id}>
        {job.title}
     </p>
    )}
   </div>
 );
}
```

Is there a way to pass on the key/id via the clicked prop - back up to the onClickHandler?

I have looked at other similar questions on here and have tried to use bind to add the key to the clicked prop but am having real trouble passing the key on to the onClickHandler. Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

How about passing a function to **onClick**.

You can the pass along arguments to **props.clicked()**.

How about this:

```
const Container = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.jobs.map(job => 
        <p onClick={() => props.clicked(job.id)} key={job.id}>
          {job.title}
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: That works great, I didn't realise I could do this - thank you!

Comment: I had this same problem and your solution worked, but I'm not sure why this works. Could you explain why passing an arrow function in as the prop allows you to call this function with an argument, but just passing the function in as the prop doesn't allow an argument to be used?

Comment: @AdamStox `onClick` expects a function which it will call when the element is clicked. When the function is called it will pass in the **event** object. Therefore, if you had `onClick={props.clicked}` then it would get called as `props.clicked(e)`. However, using an inline function allows you to ignore the **event** parameter: `(e) => props.clicked(job.id)`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, with the clickHandler function, you get an event object in the argument:

```
onClickHandler = (event) => {// use the event obj to get key/id };
```

You can use that event object to find the key/id of any element inside the target element you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind` to pass the arguments list back to the listener.

```
<p onClick={ props.clicked.bind(null, job.id) } key={job.id}>
```

And first argument when the event is invoked has the `id`

```
onClickHandler = (id) => {
   doSomething(id);
};

return (
   <Container jobs={this.props.jobs} clicked={this.onClickHandler} />
);
```